# jquery draggable position relative to droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/6no66j16/

I am dragging "#draggable" element over to the ".droptarget"

How can I get realtime position of mouse/draggable event relative to droppable element?

The "over" method inside droppable does not update mouse position (like hover position). How can I get realtime hover position relative to droppable?

```
      over: function (event, ui) {
          $(this).css("background-color", "red");
          $(".droptarget").removeClass("hidden");

          $(".droptarget").mousemove(function (event) {
              var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
              msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
              console.log(msg);
          });

      }
```

Thanks!